# IIS 7.5 express returns 404 for FireFox (Works in IE and Chrome)

Tags: firefox, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I'm having trouble accessing my IIS 7.5 express site in FireFox but i can access it in IE and Chrome. The site returns a 404 error for FireFox for almost all directories.

This is the log from the Firefox requests

```
2012-06-25 18:30:38.834 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 401 -2147024891 6423 274 15 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" "-" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 2
2012-06-25 18:30:38.834 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 401 -2146893042 6927 352 0 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" "-" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 1
2012-06-25 18:30:38.850 127.0.0.1 "DOMAIN\USERNAME" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 404 -2147024894 5250 516 15 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" "-" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 0
```

This is the Chrome Requests

```
2012-06-25 18:30:56.908 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 401 -2147024891 6399 457 0 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 2
2012-06-25 18:30:58.408 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 401 -2146893042 6903 560 0 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 1
2012-06-25 18:30:58.502 127.0.0.1 "DOMAIN\USERNAME" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET /default.aspx - 200 0 1728 580 15 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 0
2012-06-25 18:30:58.502 127.0.0.1 "DOMAIN\USERNAME" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET / - 200 0 1728 580 93 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "-" "-" "localhost:8080" 0
2012-06-25 18:30:58.517 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET /Scripts/jquery-1.5.js - 401 -2147024891 6470 451 0 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "http://localhost:8080/" "-" "localhost:8080" 2
2012-06-25 18:30:58.533 127.0.0.1 "-" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET /Scripts/jquery-1.5.js - 401 -2146893042 6974 554 15 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "http://localhost:8080/" "-" "localhost:8080" 1
2012-06-25 18:30:58.548 127.0.0.1 "DOMAIN\USERNAME" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET /Scripts/jquery-1.5.js - 404 -2147024894 5302 574 15 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "http://localhost:8080/" "-" "localhost:8080" 0
2012-06-25 18:30:58.564 127.0.0.1 "DOMAIN\USERNAME" "GARY-LOCAL-DEV" "-" 127.0.0.1 GET /Styles/Woodlands.css - 304 0 308 551 46 8080 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5" "ASP.NET_SessionId=obkmwr5elb3iruk0gykhup1i" "http://localhost:8080/" "-" "localhost:8080" 0
```

I have Windows NTLM authentication turned on for the server because this is a dev for an intranet site. This did work last week just fine but i noticed a FireFox update this morning. Any ideas if that update is the cause or a red herring and any suggestions on where to look for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the first thing that hit my eyes: You have a session id for the Chrome requests but not for the Firefox requests.

I guess the Firefox update just simply cleared your session cookies, hence the difference. If I'm right, the problem can reproduced in any browser after clearing your session cookies.